# How to adjust the following split equation to be left aligned

Tags: math-mode

I want to have the split equation  on LHS to be left aligned. My 2 attempts are shown below, i.e., option A and option B. Please see the source code for the details.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,vmargin=15mm,hmargin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Hey baby!
    \item
    $\!
    \begin{aligned}[t]
    2-3x(x-1)\\
    {}-3(x-2y)(x+2y)
        &=  \!
                \begin{multlined}[t][4cm]
                    2 -3x^2 +3x\\
                    {}-3(x^2 +2xy -2xy -4y^2)
                \end{multlined}\\
        &=  \!
                \begin{multlined}[t][4cm]
                    2 -3x^2 +3x\\
                    {}-3(x^2 -4y^2)
                \end{multlined}\\
        &=  \!
                \begin{multlined}[t][4cm]
                    2 -3x^2 +3x\\
                    {}-3x^2 +12y^2
                \end{multlined}\\
        &= -6x^2 +3x +12y^2 +2
    \end{aligned}
    $
    \item
    $\!
    \begin{aligned}[t]
    \begin{multlined}[t][4cm]
    2-3x(x-1)\\
    {}-3(x-2y)(x+2y)
    \end{multlined}\\
        &=  \!
                \begin{multlined}[t][4cm]
                    2 -3x^2 +3x\\
                    {}-3(x^2 +2xy -2xy -4y^2)
                \end{multlined}\\
        &=  \!
                \begin{multlined}[t][4cm]
                    2 -3x^2 +3x\\
                    {}-3(x^2 -4y^2)
                \end{multlined}\\
        &=  \!
                \begin{multlined}[t][4cm]
                    2 -3x^2 +3x\\
                    {}-3x^2 +12y^2
                \end{multlined}\\
        &= -6x^2 +3x +12y^2 +2
    \end{aligned}
    $
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this will give you option b:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,vmargin=15mm,hmargin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{2}
\item
$
  \begin{multlined}[t]
  2-3x(x-1)\\
    \begin{aligned}
    {}-3(x-2y)(x+2y)
    &=  \!
            \begin{multlined}[t][4cm]
                2 -3x^2 +3x\\
                {}-3(x^2 +2xy -2xy -4y^2)
            \end{multlined}\\
    &=  \!
            \begin{multlined}[t][4cm]
                2 -3x^2 +3x\\
                {}-3(x^2 -4y^2)
            \end{multlined}\\
    &=  \!
                \begin{multlined}[t][4cm]
                    2 -3x^2 +3x\\
                    {}-3x^2 +12y^2
                \end{multlined}\\
        &= -6x^2 +3x +12y^2 +2
    \end{aligned}
  \end{multlined}
$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `\!` needed for the outer `multlined`?

Comment: @Bugbusters -- `\!` actually shouldn't be needed anywhere (in my example code); placing the `&` before the `=` establishes the correct spacing for the sign of relation.  you don't want to start the expression with `\!` to avoid placing it too close to the item number, making that look like it's part of the equation.